# How to specify relative path in local.properties?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to specify the path to the Solr configset in my local.properties.I tried the absolute path in my file which worked fine, then replaced it with ${HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR} which also works fine.

However my worry is that when this code goes to the Cloud environment where configuration is loaded by manifest.json which refers to the local.properties to be used and the solr folder is in same directory(same as local.properties).How do I give a relative path which works for both local as well as Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own key for your custom path like below. These are defined in platform OOB.

```
HYBRIS_BIN_DIR=${platformhome}/../../bin
HYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR=${platformhome}/../../config
HYBRIS_DATA_DIR=${platformhome}/../../data
HYBRIS_LOG_DIR=${platformhome}/../../log
HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR=${platformhome}/../../temp/hybris
```

Answer (score 0):

Hybris Platform takes care of relative path

The above-mentioned path is generally used by the build callbacks.